Copy AWS S3 Bucket Between Accounts Cross-Region
We need to copy the contents of a bucket to a new account in a different AWS region.
The bucket contains ±200K objects, most of which are archived (Glacier), and a large portion of them are quite big (>10GB).
At first we tried the following:

Batch script to restore all the objects.
Configure a Lambda trigger to handle restore completion per object.
Execute the copy method with boto3 on the Lambda function.

This works well for smaller objects (up to ~2GB), but larger objects take longer than the maximum allowed Lambda duration (15min).
To complete the rest of them (>10K objects) we must use some VM, however VMs are forced to be in a VPC and for some reason boto3 can't handle cross-region copy commands from within a VPC:
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: VPC endpoints do not support cross-region requests

So we resorted to download and upload each object. This takes too long for the amount of objects we need to copy.
Can anyone offer a better solution?
NOTE #1: AWS has something called Batch Jobs which may be relevant, but it was a bit difficult to configure and for some reason requires both source and destination buckets to enable versioning (which is disable in this case).
NOTE #2: We have a role on the destination account which has access to the source account and S3 requests are called with the requester paying for them.

We are now trying to use DataSync as outlined here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/tutorial_s3-s3-cross-account-transfer.html

Use fargate instead of lambda https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

Also why not use services such as AWS DataSync which will make this very easy?

When copying objects between buckets, the command is sent to the destination bucket. It would appear that your code is running in the source region, hence the error message. If you remove the VPC Endpoint it should work because the command will be sent to the destination bucket in the other region. Alternatively, deploy your code in the destination region and use a VPC Endpoint there. Note that boto3 simply sends the command to copy and then the S3 service copies the files. Thus, your code using boto3 doesn't do the actual copy itself.

@LucasM.Uriarte see my comment above

@JohnRotenstein our code was actually running in the destination region.

@JohnRotenstein Also, regarding S3 copying the file by itself, I'm not sure that's entirely true because you must wait for the copy command to finish, you can't just send it async.

Eventually we did use DataSync. One caveat is that you need to manually take care of restoring the objects before running the DataSync task.
The AWS tutorial on how do that is here.
